# What LLC type in wifi

Tags: ieee-802.11

I'm trying to understand how wifi (802.11) networks operates.

I found that in 802.11, the 802.2 (LLC) layer is used and that this layer can follow different types.

- type 1 : no connection, no ack
- type 2 : connected mode with ack
- type 3 : ack but no connection

I suppose wifi uses the type 2 but i can't find any clear information on that.

Do you have clear information on this ?

Comment: It depends on the mode (infrastructure, ad-hoc) used.

Comment: You mean, in ad hoc mode => type 3 and in infrastructure mode => type 2 because of the station - access point coupling ?